Trying to add a <div> that will create under a specified page but can't single out the page
I am making a calendar in codepen, I have gotten much further than I thought I could but I am stuck again at adding the events to the specified date. What it currently does is find which day you want the event to be on, but then it can't add a card to that date using the month, time, ect. This issue seems to come from there being one set of divs but I don't know anymore.
This is the pen, you should only need to look into the following areas:
HTML Lines 241 and on
CSS Line 546 and what's in that bracket
JS Functions
   saveE()

   viewDay(clicked_id)

   Calendar(Month,Year) Lines 66-81

https://codepen.io/CoderCasey/pen/KKYZVBE
I have tried appending a child, innerHTML, and making a new iterated section (HTML 241 to end) with the id's = to the day number. None of that worked, the closest I can get is what I supplied.
